# C# redirect ffmpeg output to textbox in realtime

Tags: c#, redirect, ffmpeg, textbox, output

So I've been reading a lot through stackoverflow, and I found a lot of questions trying to deal with a similar problem as mine, but none of the solutions worked for me. So here is what I have:

I have a WPF GUI application which launches ffmpeg by the following code:

```
        private void convertbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string resdir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\res";
        Extract("ADC", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\res", "res", "ffmpeg.exe");

        string ffdir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\res\\ffmpeg.exe";
        string arg = @"-progress progresslog.txt -y -activation_bytes ";
        string arg1 = @" -i ";
        string arg2 = @" -ab 80k -vn ";
        string abytes = bytebox.Text;
        string arguments = arg + abytes + arg1 + openFileDialog1.FileName + arg2 + saveFileDialog1.FileName;

        Process ffm = new Process();
        ffm.StartInfo.FileName = ffdir;
        ffm.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        ffm.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ffm.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffm.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        ffm.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffm.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        ffm.Start();
        ffm.WaitForExit();

        ffm.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Conversion Complete!");

        File.Delete("progresslog.txt");
        Directory.Delete(resdir, true);
    }
```

So on this application I do also have other processes, which display their output to the textbox after finishing what they are doing, so but since ffmpeg outputs it's conversion progress in the cmd output, I need to get exactly that being displayed in the textbox in realtime.

And I am pretty sure that ffmpeg outputs into stderr same w/ ffprobe.

I'd appreciate any help, since days of googleing didn't help me with anything so far.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add these lines around `ffm.Start()`. This should write the `ffmpeg` output to the Debug console. If that works you can adjust the code to write the output to your WPF GUI.

```
ffm.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
ffm.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => { Debug.WriteLine($"STD: {ea.Data}"); };
ffm.ErrorDataReceived += (s, ea) => { Debug.WriteLine($"ERR: {ea.Data}"); };
ffm.Start();
ffm.BeginOutputReadLine();
ffm.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

See also this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994610/c-sharp-get-process-output-while-running)