# How to get process output

Tags: python, .net, .net-core

My C# code:

```
static string pyExe = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python.exe";

var psi = new Process();

string name = "show_ing.py";
string script = "C:\\Users\\micosin\\source\\practiceDotNet\\python\\" + name;
C:\Users\micosin\source\practiceDotNet\python

psi.StartInfo.FileName = pyExe;
psi.StartInfo.Arguments = script;
psi.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
psi.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
psi.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
psi.Start();

psi.BeginOutputReadLine();
psi.WaitForExit();

...

static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

Python show_ing.py script for creating test output:

```
# -*- encoding=utf-8 -*-

import sys
import time

print(sys.argv)
while True:
    print('PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want get output while the script is running (hence the infinite loop). In testing I only get the output of the script if it exits (no loop).

Comment: Does your callback get called at all? I.e. did you put a breakpoint in p_OutputDataReceived? Maybe your output is going to stderr? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994610/c-sharp-get-process-output-while-running

Comment: yes.  i already saw that.
the p_OutputDataReceived will called when py going to end. 
for example the py like as below:
print('Doneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee')
time.sleep(10)
print('Doneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee')


then the callback will be called at seconds later

Comment: if i edit my python remove the sleep method and infinite loop .
the code is correct

Comment: oh, you are using print not println (or whatever the python equivalent is). It's probably not flushing output until it exits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function

Comment: thank you so much.
got it point,   i wrong searching keywords of buffer.
haha  not have concepts about buffer.
and Now i know thank you

Comment: If you've solved the problem you may want to answer it (in an answer).

Comment: got it . thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question solution:
get the new concepts about [buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function).

just to flush buffering to output( use print("Hello world!", flush=True) ).  the C# process can be get the output